# Javascript string to date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have this string in Javascript

```
"/Date(1317772800000)/"
```

and I'd like to display it as a meaningful date in my page.  Currently, when I output the variable that contains this date I get the following displayed on my page

```
/Date(1317772800000)/
```

What I'd like is to display this in the format DD MM YYYY like so

```
10 05 2011
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Start by using new Date(datestr);

Comment: I guess your trying to evaluate that string then what about using eval as in: `eval("/Date(1317772800000)/".replace('/',''));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var date = new Date(Number.parseFloat('/Date(1317772800000)/'.substring(6)));
var newdate = date.getMonth() +' ' +date.getDate() +' ' +date.getFullYear()
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have your date in a string provided then first you need to extract the number:

```
var strDate = "/Date(1317772800000)/";
var dateInt = strDate.replace("/Date(","").replace(")/","");
var date = new Date(parseInt(dateInt))
```

This gives you a JavaScript date object that you can do pretty much a lot with, if you want simple check just execute:

```
alert(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) i.e.:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a')
```

Then you can do:

```
moment(1317772800000).format("MMM Do YY");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
unixtime = 1317772800000;
var newDate = new Date();
newDate.setTime(unixtime);
dateString = newDate.toUTCString();

alert(dateString);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/3SLMb/)**